# Rails link that updates integer in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a column in my table that is an integer. I'm trying to make a link in my application that puts a specific integer in that column.

i.e. :

User clicks link labeled 0 => record in DB sets record to 0

User clicks link labeled 1 => record in DB sets record to 1

ETC. . .

In the VIEW:

```
<%= link_to "0", 
     {:controller => "application", 
      :action => 'rate_app'}, 
      :class => "rate_btn", 
      :method=> :put 
%>
```

In the CONTROLLER:

```
def rate_app(current_user, rating)
  current_user.nps_rating = rating
  if current_user.save
    redirect_to mypage_path
  end
end
```

Does anyone see a conflict/mess-up in the code? I get an error.

Comment: I also don't know what the question is.  It's also odd to use the application controller directly.  Normally you create your own model specific controllers.  It's more 'rails-y' to use restful resources if applicable.

Comment: I guess my question is regarding the fact that the above code doesn't work. I got an error.

Comment: Any chance of maybe hinting what the "error" said...

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding information to your db, it should be done via a POST. Links are a GET. With that being said, I would suggest looking at button_to to solve this one.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to